# Control bidirectional reference event (video, slider bar)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

My Blazor page have a video and a slider bar.

Slider bar are moved according to video time.

Also, Video time are moved when user controls slider bar's progress.

In other words, slider bar's **onchange** event affects to video and video's **timeupdate** event affecst to slider bar as well.
Because of this, when I control slider bar, the slider bar is drawn briefly where it was, not where I moved it, and then comes back to where I moved it.

I'd like to stop video's event when I control slider bar.

Below is my code. I'm using [Radzen](https://blazor.radzen.com/slider) for slider and [Blazored.Video](https://github.com/Blazored/Video) for video

======= razor page =======

```
@*video component*@
<BlazoredVideo VideoEventOptions="options"
               TimeUpdateEvent=""="OnTimeUpdate"
               id="video1"
               style="width:100%;height:100%"
               controls="controls">
    <source src="@video1Path" type="video/mp4" />
</BlazoredVideo>

@*slider Component*@
<RadzenSlider @bind-Value="@currentVideoDuration" TValue="int" Min="0" Max="100" Change="@(e => OnChangeSliderValue(e))"></RadzenSlider>
```

======= cs code =======

```
public void OnChangeSliderValue(dynamic value)
{
    int nValue = value;
    JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("VideoTimeChange", "video1", nValue);
}

public void OnTimeUpdate(VideoState state)
{
    int currentTime = (int)state.CurrentTime;
    currentVideoDuration = (int)state.CurrentTime;
}
```

====== js code =======

```
function VideoTimeChange(id, time) {
    var vid = document.getElementById(id);
    vid.currentTime = time;
}
```

Please share your knowledge about JavaScript, Blazor

Answer (score 0):

Try this - because everything happens async, if you set a flag, then run the JS and await it, then reset the flag - the code in the OnTimeUpdate method can be made aware that it should ignore updates for a while.

```
bool allowTimeUpdates = true;
public async Task OnChangeSliderValue(dynamic value)
{
    allowTimeUpdates = false;
    int nValue = value;
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("VideoTimeChange", "video1", nValue);
    allowTimeUpdates = true;
}
public void OnTimeUpdate(VideoState state)
{
    if (allowTimeUpdates)
    {
        int currentTime = (int)state.CurrentTime;
        currentVideoDuration = (int)state.CurrentTime;
    }
}
```